# Assembly signing fails after changing project file

Tags: c#, assemblies, assembly-signing

We use a third-party tool, i.e. we have the sources and include those into our project.

In a project file there are the tags "SignAssembly" and "AssemblyOriginatorKeyFile".

Since we use this tool, it read like:

```
<SignAssembly Condition="Exists('..\Original.snk')">true</SignAssembly>
<AssemblyOriginatorKeyFile Condition="Exists('..\Original.snk')">..\Original.snk</AssemblyOriginatorKeyFile>
```

**The file `Original.snk` never existed.**

Recently, I had to update the sources and I took over a change from "Original.snk" to "New.snk". The file `New.snk` also doesn't exist.

However, after that change, the distribution build failed, because the assemblies weren't signed.

> CSC (0): Assembly generation failed -- Referenced assembly '[assembly]' does not have a strong name

I don't see why the mere change of the name causes an error. I assume I overlooked an important change some place else but I failed to find it.

Does any one have an idea what I have to look for? Are there any files that might be related to assembly signing and needed to be updated, too?

I thoroughly looked at any project files that may be related but I don't find anything suspiciously.

---

Note, the issue can surely be fixed by linking to an existing .snk-file, but I'm trying to understand the reason of the failure.

Note, my understanding of this signing rigmarole is for sure too little, but reading articles about basics (like that [this one](http://www.windowsdevcenter.com/pub/a/dotnet/2003/04/28/strongnaming.html)) didn't give me any further ideas.